# Why does this simple transformation yield an annulus (ring) shape?

Tags: normal-distribution

As shown in: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf
using the transformation :

$g(z) = \frac{z}{10} + \frac{z}{||z||}$

when each component of $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is normally distributed yields an annulus shape when plotted in the plane.

However, could someone explain why? What is the intuition in the equation that transforms the Gaussian into an annulus? I didn't really find an "equation of the annulus" or anything that explains that clearly.

See image here:

[image]

I did code it in Python and it does work so the question is just mathematical: why does it produce this ring-shape?

I think it is probably just a result of vector addition: adding a (normally distributed) unit vector $z$ to a 10 times smaller (normally distr.) vector $z$ seems to produce this ring, but I wonder how to intuitively come to this?

Comment: Note that $g(z)=z/\| z \|$ produces a perfect ring.  The z/10 term does very little becuase most of the random samples have $\| z \| < 2$.  The $z/10$ term is small compared to $z/ \| z \|$.

Comment: oh yes i just got it yes the z/||z|| is in fact a unit vector so every gaussian vector is just reduced to a unit vector on the unit circle!

Answer (score 2):

> I think it is probably just a result of vector addition.

Yes, pretty much.

$$h(z) = \frac{z}{|z|}$$

is uniformly distributed on the unit circle. Adding $z/10$ to this translates each sample further outward away from the circle, by a distance given by a (narrow) half-normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would explain it to myself like this:

since $z/||z||$ is a unit vector, then each of the Gaussian $z$ vectors (which have any arbitrary norm) are rescaled to unit norm but of course keep their direction. So they would be as Brian Borchers said on a "perfect ring" and the +z/10 adds a bit of "variance".